# Ensuring whether file is copied successfully

Tags: c#

I have a file which I am copying to some location. Below is the code snippet -

```
//Document Status = Pending
var triggerFileWriter = new StringWriter();
triggerFileWriter.WriteLine("Only for test");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fullTriggerFilename, triggerFileWriter.ToString());
triggerFileWriter.Dispose();

if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullTriggerFilename))
{
    // Document Status = Processed
}
```

Is `File.Exists` check sufficient to update the document status?
I am not worried about if file is not copied over and document status not updated. Because there is a timer job running every 10 minutes, 'Pending' items will be automatically picked up in the next run.

Is there any possibility of file copying being interrupted - which can result in a file but not actually copied completely?
What changes I can make to my code to address if that happens.

Thank you!

Comment: There is *write cache*, so you have to [flush](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383324/1997232) to ensure what it's really safe. Apart from not getting exceptions during `WriteAllText` of course.

Comment: @Sinatr `Flush` doesn't wait for the HDD to physically save the data either (anymore). On modern systems, there simply isn't a way to be sure unless you have a way of checking the file integrity - or relying on file systems that allow atomic file creation (like NTFS). More importantly, it doesn't solve the OP's problem - he doesn't need to ensure the file is properly written, he just needs to know whether the file he's about to process now does or doesn't need to be processed.

Comment: @Luaan, did you check the linked question in my comment?

Comment: @Sinatr Yup. `FlushFileBuffers` *still* doesn't ensure the file being physically written. There's no way even for the *OS* to force the HDD to save the internal buffer. True, it forces Windows to *send* the data to the HDD, but the HDD has its own internal caches. The uses for `FlushFileBuffers` are quite niche - and for people who want to feel more in control than they really are :D

Comment: @Sinatr Or, to be more exact, it *might* work, or it *might not*. And in any case, you're killing your performance - caching exists for a reason. A nice article on the topic is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/09/10059575.aspx - and I'm pretty sure there's devices that ignore even those messages nowadays (though I can't find the reference to *that*). Of course, if you want to force this in an application like this, you wouldn't use `FlushFileBuffers` - you'd simply disable the buffering with `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

Comment: @Luaan, *HDD internal cache* is the key. OS function probably doesn't go that far (and/or some manufacturers will cheat it anyway to get higher benchmark). You are right. I wouldn't consider performance when data integrity might be of the highest priority, but flushing simply won't work. And UPS may fail too (it may fail simultaneously with power failure ^^). The only way left is to use `File.Exists`, but provide another means of data integrity, e.g. [making backups](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7957544/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way to know for sure is to compare the whole file, byte-by-byte, to the file you're trying to write. This is not exactly cheap, of course - you could have just as easily overwritten the file anyway.

On NTFS, files that weren't properly "committed" are basically deleted, so the `File.Exists` is fine. This may not be the case when using e.g. FAT-32, or when saving over a networked file system.

File size might help in that case - unless you pre-allocate the file in advance (which is quite a good practice for performance). Even without pre-allocating, it's quite possible for the file to be sized properly, but still missing data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually the file is being copied over a networked file system - to another server. Can I rely on File.Exists?

Comment: @iniki That mainly depends on whether you have control over the remote side as well. If it's a Windows server with NTFS, you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an hash function such as [SHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) or [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) on the original file and store it. Then apply the same hash function on the copied file and compare the two hashes. They must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `File.WriteAllText` method. That means your job will be done or you'll get an exception. So, you have a guarantee given by .NET I/O API that file was properly written.

But you'll never have guarantee that it exists in some resource. So you don't need to call `File.Exists`. Just don't rely on this. Everything can happen.