# .NET File.Copy wait for finalization

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a UI that copies files to a USB stick with a progress bar.

When, at an API level, File.Copy completes, I display a success message to the user. The problem is, users pull out the drive when I show a success message, and windows is still doing "finalization". Pulling the drive out before finalization calls files to not be shown or to be corrupted.

The question.

How do I make File.Copy lock until the drive is actually completely finalized? The sticks could be FAT32 or NTFS (most likely, large files on our device).

Comment: I assume that by "finalized" you mean write caches are flushed and file handles closed? If so, you might be able to take control of the file copy yourself so you've got a reference to the stream. Then you can [forcibly flush to disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383324/how-to-ensure-all-data-has-been-physically-written-to-disk/3992428#3992428) (.Net 4+) Failing that you can call the [Win32API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to force the OS to flush the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possbile, instead of using File.Copy() how about switching to StreamWriter or BinaryWriter and using the Flush() method? [StreamWriter Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush.aspx) and [BinaryWriter Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.flush.aspx) should force everything to be written to disk ASAP.

Comment: Are you sure that this will work? We had still problems in some cases when we only called flush on the stream, because the data was still in some "disk cache"?. After we called FlushFileBuffers on a handle to the volume directly (see remarks) the data was really written to disk.

Comment: Only true if you call `Stream.Flush(True)` (.Net4+). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3992428/156755

Comment: @Basic Ah that explains why we had to call FlushFileBuffers

Comment: That is good to know. Hopefully the OP is using .NET >= 4 since this seems to be a quick, easy way to handle flushing :)

Answer (score 0):

Call the WinApi [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) funktion via PInvoke.
Or tell the users in the message that they have to properly eject the USB stick.