# What API to retrieve PC Disk Drive properties?

Tags: c#, disk, drives

I need to check disk name and whether the "enable write caching on the device" is enabled or not. so far I tried api method  DriveInfo.GetDrives , But it doesn't have any property or methods that can return information I am looking for.

```
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);

        }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/10/09/enable-or-disable-enable-write-caching-on-disk-behavior-on-disk/ ? How did you go implementing that?

Comment: trying your solution.

Comment: it is c++ code . can you recommend any c# API to access the information

Comment: Any C# API would use the same functions under the hood.

Comment: This answer tells you how to use it from C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5917971/2557128